# Axiomatizability of class of the language $L=\{ = \} $

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I was solving a mock exam and there is a "tricky" question, for me at least. It seem to me impossible that question 1) and 4) are both true. I would love to understand

Let $L$ a language with the symbol $ \{=\} $ and $C$ a class of $L$-structure. We say that $C$ is axiomatizable if there exists a theory $T$ of $L$ such that for all $L$-structure $\mathcal{M} $ we have that $ \mathcal{M} \in C $ if and only if $ \mathcal{M} \models T$.
We say that $ C$ is finitely axiomatizable if there exists a finite theory $T$.

1. Let $ L $ be the language consisting only of the symbol $ = $ and $ C$  the class of the finite $L$-structures. Is $C$ axiomatizable? Is $C$ finitely axiomatizable?
   (Both answers: no)
2. Let $ L$ be a language of the first order. Prove that if $C$ is finitely axiomatizable then the complementary class is also finitely axiomatizable.
3. Let $L$ be the language consisting only of the symbol $ = $ and $C$ the class of the infinite $L$-structures. Is $C$ axiomatizable? Is $C$ finitely axiomatizable?
   (First answer yes, the second answer no by point 2)

In the following let $ L $ be the language consisting only of the symbol $ = $

4. Write a formula $F$ that axiomatizes the class of the $L$-structure for which the cardinality of its domains is $n$, with $n=1,2$ or $7$.
5. Write a formula $G$ whose finite models are exactly the $L$-structure for which the cardinality of its domains is $n$, with $n\neq 1,2,7$.
6. Give a theory whose finite models are exactly the $L$-structure with even cardinality.

Comment: What is your question ? there is a sentence $\sigma_n$ which says there are exactly $n$ elements. So for 4) take $\sigma_1\vee \sigma_2\vee \sigma_7$

Comment: To pre-empt downvotes, note that the OP is **not** simply listing a bunch of homework questions and asking us to solve them: their specific question is "It seem to me impossible that question 1) and 4) are both true. I would love to understand." That said, I think this could be made a bit clearer; there's no need to include *all* the homework problems, and the actual question of the post should be better highlighted.

Comment: I had no problem about constructing the formula. Sorry if i listed all questions I thought might be helpful. My question was actually why the answer of question 1) is no but 4) is possible to do.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking why the following two true statements are not in tension with each other:

- The class $\mathbb{K}_{\mathit{fin}}$ of finite $\{=\}$-structures is not axiomatizable.
- The class $\mathbb{K}_{1,2,7}$ of $\{=\}$-structures of size either $1$, $2$, or $7$ is axiomatizable - indeed, can be axiomatized by a single sentence.

The silly-but-totally-correct response is simply: these are statements about different classes of structures! Since $\mathbb{K}_{\mathit{fin}}\not=\mathbb{K}_{1,2,7}$ - there are finite sets of size other than $1$, $2$, or $7$ (exercise) - there is no reason to expect them to have the same properties.

The more serious answer is that you should look at the proof that $\mathbb{K}_{\mathit{fin}}$ is not axiomatizable. It relies on a particular property of the set of finite cardinals (in order to let us apply compactness appropriately), which the set $\{1,2,7\}$ does not have. So there is in fact a "dividing line" here: there is a very simple characterization of those classes of cardinals $C$ whose associated classes of structures $$\mathbb{Card}_C:=\{\mathcal{A}: \vert\mathcal{A}\vert\in C\}$$ are axiomatizable. This is the real theorem which you should tease out here. I'm not going to spoil it entirely, but note that in this notation we have $\mathbb{K}_{\mathit{fin}}=\mathbb{Card}_{\mathbb{N}}$; now, as a set of cardinals, what nice property does $\mathbb{N}$ **not** have?

Comment: Not OP's question, but can 6) be done with a finite theory ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus No - you can show that for every specific $\{=\}$-sentence $\varphi$, if $\varphi$ has arbitrarily large finite models then $\neg\varphi$ does *not* have arbitrarily large finite models. More snappily, all $\{=\}$-spectra are finite or cofinite.

Comment: And how is that done, quantifier elimination ?

Comment: Although if you deviated from the requirements of the question and instead used a language $L$ with a unary function symbol $f$, then the axiom that $f$ is an involution with no fixed points would work for (6).

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Nope, just very coarse considerations. Suppose $\varphi$ has bi-infinite spectrum. Then both $\varphi$ and $\neg\varphi$ have infinite models $M,N$. By downward Lowenheim-Skolem we can assume $M$ and $N$ are countable, but there is only one countable structure up to isomorphism in the empty language so $M\cong N$ - a contradiction.

Comment: Nice proof......

Comment: So the class $ \mathbb{K}_{A} $ of $\{=\}$-structures whose domain is of cardinality $n$ with $n \in A$ and $A \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) $ is always axtiomatizable for any finite $A$? But not for $A$ having cardinality $ \aleph_0$ ?

Comment: @3m0o Yes, that's true. One can in fact say more, though - we can completely characterize the classes of cardinals, finite *or* infinite, which correspond to axiomatizable classes. This takes you past the question at hand, but I think is both worth your time and will help de-mystify things (thinking about how the finite 'sits inside' the infinite will make the dichotomy of your comment less odd).

Comment: Wait, are you sure that's true? If $ T = \{ \varphi_{a_1}, \dots, \varphi_{a_n} \} $ si an axiomatization of the class $ \mathbb{K}_{A} $ where $A$ is finite, and $\{a_i: 1 \leq 1 \leq n \} = A$ then $ T' = \{ \psi \} $ where $ \psi = \bigwedge_j \neg \varphi_{a_j} $ is not an axiomatization of $ \mathbb{K}_{ \mathbb{N} \setminus A} $ ? Hence we can give a finite axiomatization of $ \mathbb{K}_{A} $ for every finite $A$ and cofinite $ A$

Comment: @3m0o Sorry, I misinterpreted you: I thought "But not for $A$ having cardinality $\aleph_0$" meant "not *necessarily* for $A$ having cardinality $\aleph_0$." (And note that the last sentence of your comment matches the last sentence of my first comment to Rene above.)

Comment: Thanks, I misspoke as well. Anyway, I guess that this generalizes to all languages whose signature is just $\{ R \}$ where $R$ is just any binary relation.